# Azure logic app - Could not retrieve values. The environment name cannot be null or empty when posting teams message with power virtual agent

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-virtual-agents

Using an Azure Logic App to post a teams message in a chat with power virtual agent and got this error "Could not retrieve values. The environment name cannot be null or empty"

I already have my chatbot installed in the teams app and can already use it in power automate, but when I try to use inside the logic app the bot does not show

[image]

I tried exporting the bot from power automate to logic app but didn't work

Comment: Why dont you simply use User or Flow Bot?

Comment: because the user and the flow bot do not have the functionalities of a chatbot...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, and I feel this is a bug in Azure Logic apps and I have raised a [GitHub Ticket](https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/1012).

I have done the same way as you have and got Flow bot , User but not with Power Virtual Agents as you have mentioned.

[image]

Alternatively I have used Flow Bot and User it worked for me:
[image]

Output:

[image]